# Calling a function inside a function [PHP, Laravel, Eloquentl]

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, octobercms

I am using October CMS built on Laravel, and I am having some strange issues I am not sure how to interpret.

**Code Sample 1: Works fine (Component EstateList)**

```
public function onRun()
{
  $this->listEstates();
}

/**
 * Pulls all the estates from the model
 *
 * @return $estateList
 */
protected function listEstates()
{
  $estateList = RealEstate::all();

  return $estateList;
}
```

**Code Sample 2: Doesn't work (Component EstateDetails)**

```
public function onRun()
{
  $this->show();
}

/**
 * Returns the slug and display individual Estate Object
 *
 * @return $pageDetails
 */
 protected function show()
 {
   $slug = $this->param('slug');
   $pageDetails = RealEstate::find($slug);

   echo $slug; //returns slug as it should
   echo $pageDetails; //empty

   if ($pageDetails) {
     return $pageDetails;
   } else {
     return \Response::make('Page not found', 404);
   }
 }
```

If I just put the code of show() into the function onRun() it works fine. Why does echo `echo $pageDetails` return empty on the **Code Sample 2?** if it is ran in a seperate function `show()`.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to `RealEstate::where('slug', '=', $slug)->firstOrFail();`. The `find` bit searches the ID table for the column, not the slug.

Answer (score 0):

You are not 'returning' the Response from `show()`

Try changing `$this->show();` to return `return $this->show();` in `onRun()`

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your code to this

```
public function onRun()
{
  return  $this->show();
}

/**
 * Returns the slug and display individual Estate Object
 *
 * @return $pageDetails
 */
 protected function show()
 {
   $slug = $this->param('slug');
   $pageDetails = RealEstate::where('slug', '=', $slug)->firstOrFail();;

   echo $slug; //returns slug as it should
   echo $pageDetails; //empty

   if ($pageDetails) {
     return $pageDetails;
   } else {
     return \Response::make('Page not found', 404);
   }
 }
```

Hopefully This will solve your problem